# How to upgrade libpng in Amazon AWS using yum

Tags: amazon-web-services, yum

I need at least libpng 1.5 installed in my server.

Client sysadmins (not reachable to me) installed my software on Amazon AWS and gave me root access.

Now this setup throws errors, that shared library libpng15 is not there.

```
# yum install libpng
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Package 2:libpng-1.2.49-2.14.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

This is clearly wrong, there is a newer version

Even if Amazon considers this unsecure and unstable, is this possible to get this newer version 1.5 through yum somehow?

Comment: Why are you using Amazon Linux?

Comment: This is fairly typical for Amazon Linux, packages are usually out of date. Your two options tend to be download source and build it yourself, or find another repo, add it to yum, and install it from there.

Comment: @MichaelHampton This is my client's choice. They are Australian company, whose IT department is in Vietnam and people who pay me are their UK subsidiary marketing department. This is their corporate rule to use  Amazon Linux, as their main app system is running on these.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend finding a different way to resolve this. Adding a package from a different distro through YUM, especially when this package already exists, and it's a client's machine sounds... hazardous.

If you can get your client to use CentOS rather than Amazon Linux (a stretch, I guess), or if you can containerize your software these could likely be more robust solutions.

Consider explaining to your customer that this is will probably be a source of trouble otherwise.
Create an AMI of the instance before doing any of these solutions.

Before choosing any of these solutions, you need to exclude the libpng package from it's current repo. 
Find out which repo it is by `yum info libpng` and then follow the instructions from https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-fedora-centos-linux-yum-disable-certain-packages-from-being-installed/

1 You can find the appropriate Fedora Library from here: https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/ and add it's repo according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/add-repositories.html 
Add the include line in the .repo file according to https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-use-yum-repositories-on-a-centos-6-vps so as to only take the package you want.

2 You might want to look here: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361148/how-to-add-fedora-repo-to-a-centos-7-installation
for suggestions on how to rebuild from SRPM, and here: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/2/search/libpng-1.6.3
for the SRPM.

3 Or you can also take the binaries from here http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html or here: http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/ and try them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already tried to add another repo to yum, but after disabling the priorities flag to allow this, I got 4 pages of problems with existing packages :) For now I just disabled the image beautification step. And pre-generated existing images in my staging Centos. They won't need this more than once a month anyway and difference is quite small. When there is some more development to do (foreseeably in few months), then I'll return to this question.